# How to use filter query in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am writing query in Postgres with using filter in Status (Like 'UP' and 'DOWN') and that is working fine.I just want to write the same query into Oracle. I am having UP and DOWN values into same column Status. I just want to count the total no of Up and down status and also total no of Apps result. I want three total count values into this alias column Tot_App_Name, Status_Up_count, Status_down_count. How can I do it?

Table:-

```
CREATE TABLE Application_Status
(
   App_Category   VARCHAR (45) NULL,
   App_Name       VARCHAR (40) NULL,
   DB_name        VARCHAR (40) NULL,
   Server         VARCHAR (200) NULL,
   Provider       VARCHAR (250) NULL,
   Status         VARCHAR (10) NULL,
   Last_Refresh   TIMESTAMP NULL
)
```

Inserted values:-

```
insert into Application_Status values('app1','abc1','abcd1','abcd1','url11','Up',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into Application_Status values('app2','abc2','abcd2','abcd2','url12','Up',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into Application_Status values('app3','abc3','abcd3','abcd3','url13','down',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into Application_Status values('app4','abc4','abcd4','abcd4','url14','down',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
insert into Application_Status values('app5','abc5','abcd5','abcd5','url15','Up',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Postgress query (want to convert into oracle):-

```
select count(*) as "Tot_App_Name",count(*) filter (where "Status"= 'UP') as "Status_Up_count",
    count(*) filter (where "Status"= 'DOWN') as "Status_Down_count" from  "ApplicationStatus"."ApplicationStatus";
            Select * from "Application_Status"."Application_Status";
```

Expected Result:-

```
Tot_App_Name     Status_Up_count      Status_Down_count
   5                  3                     2
```

Comment: I have to admit, I don't know the filter( ... ) syntax. In standard SQL, you would do it like this:
`SELECT --place the colums you want to select here`
`FROM -- place the tables here`
`WHERE -- place the conditions for here; this is the filtering part`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
select 
  count(*) tot_app_name,
  sum(case when status = 'UP'   then 1 else 0 end) status_up_count,
  sum(case when status = 'DOWN' then 1 else 0 end) status_down_count
from application_status;
```